# How to access a usb flash drive from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, mount, usb-drive

I only have access to the command line.
I need to backup my data (on the user folder) to a pen (USB DOK).

- How can I mount a flash drive manually?
- What should be the copy command?

Comment: This was helpful for me to see a list of files and their sizes: https://www.askdavetaylor.com/access-usb-flash-thumb-drive-in-ubuntu-linux-gui-command-line-cli/

Answer (score 456, accepted):

#### 1. Find what the drive is called

You'll need to know what the drive is called to mount it. To do that fire off one of the following (ranked in order of my preference):

```
lsblk
sudo blkid
sudo fdisk -l
```

You're looking for a partition that should look something like: `/dev/sdb1`. The more disks you have the higher the letter this is likely to be. Anyway, find it and remember what it's called.

#### 2. Create a mount point (optional)

This needs to be mounted into the filesystem *somewhere*. You can usually use /mnt/ if you're being lazy and nothing else is mounted there but otherwise you'll want to create a new directory:

```
sudo  mkdir /media/usb
```

#### 3. Mount!

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
```

When you're done, just fire off:

```
sudo umount /media/usb
```

---

This answer is almost 6 years old and while the core of it still works, things like `fdisk -l` aren't the most user-friendly options. There are also new mechanisms in higher stacks for mounting devices in a sane and standard way which might not always be available.

So I've added some polish from the other answers. While you're reading this footnote and you're doing this on a desktop system, there definitely are  arguments for [using `udisksctl`, per wecac's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/865453/449). This mounts in the same way the desktop does —creating your own `/media/$USER/device` directory— but I think there are still arguments for a static mountpoint, especially when you don't want the path to change.

Udisks also relies on D-Bus, so might not be available everywhere.

Comment: the main disadvantage of this method is that it mounts the device as root. if the device is FAT formatted then the user won't be able to write to it. the /media/$USER/device mountpoint will also always be the same

Comment: All answers assume that there magically appears a /dev/sdX after putting in the USB stick. What if it doesn't? I see in the logs that it is detected, but no new /dev. lsusb show all the gory details too. Ie `sudo lsusb -vs 15:2 | grep id` gives `idVendor           0x090c Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.)`
  `idProduct          0x1000 Flash Drive`

Comment: Still works in 2022 with Ubuntu 20.x

Comment: @CarloWood I have faced a similar situation. In some logs, i think `dmesg` or something, I found that the drive was unable to power itself up. I just ended up using a different port for the drive. As far as i know there is not a way to mount a drive, whose device driver hasnt created a device file in `/dev/`

Answer (score 54):

### [`pmount`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pmount) / [`pumount`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pumount)

Install `pmount`. Mounts disks in /media/

```
pmount /dev/sdb1
pumount /dev/sdb1
```

No `sudo` needed.

Replace "sdb1" with your specific device path. For more information see the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pmount):

```
pmount  ("policy mount") is a wrapper around the standard mount program
which permits normal users to mount removable devices without a  match-
ing /etc/fstab entry.

pmount is invoked like this:

pmount device [ label ]

This  will  mount  device  to a directory below /media if policy is met
(see below). If label is given, the mount point will  be  /media/label,
otherwise it will be /media/device.
```

Comment: This worked when `mount` insisted on mounting my drive read-only.

Comment: Thanks, I knew how to do the accepted answer but was looking for something a bit easier that didn't leave me having to clear up empty folders myself.

Answer (score 18):

Use [`udisksctl`](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks) from package=`udisks2` (in both Ubuntu and Debian). Procedure is:

1. Find the ID of the block device you want to mount, using `lsblk`:

   ```
   user@machine:~$ lsblk
   NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
   sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
   ├─sda1   8:1    0  19.1M  0 part /boot/efi
   ├─sda2   8:2    0   1.8T  0 part
   └─sda3   8:3    0    16G  0 part [SWAP]
   sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
   ├─sdb1   8:17   0    37M  0 part
   ├─sdb2   8:18   0  15.9G  0 part [SWAP]
   └─sdb3   8:19   0 915.7G  0 part /
   sdc      8:32   1  14.4G  0 disk
   └─sdc1   8:33   1  14.4G  0 part
   sdd      8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk
   └─sdd1   8:49   0   1.8T  0 part
   ```

   From its size, `/dev/sdc1` seems to be the USB drive I want to mount.
2. Use `udisksctl` to mount the device. Note that `-b` == `--block-device` (to reduce typing) but I prefer long options for documentation:

   ```
   user@machine:~$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdc1
   ==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount ===
   Authentication is required to mount Kingston DT microDuo 3C (/dev/sdc1)
   Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
    1.  XXXXX,,, (user)
    2.  ,,, (YYYYY)
   Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2): 1
   Password:
   ==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
   Mounted /dev/sdc1 at /media/user/USBDRIVELABEL.
   ```

Addressing Hans Deragon's [comment below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37767/how-to-access-a-usb-flash-drive-from-the-terminal/865453#comment1474190_865453): you can also tell `udisksctl` to do `--no-user-interaction`. It does not attempt to authenticate the user, which usually "just works":

```
user@machine:~$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdc1 --no-user-interaction
# possibly some complaining here about I/O charset or need to run `fsck`
Mounted /dev/sdc1 at /media/user/USBDRIVELABEL.
```

Answer (score 12):

In addition to using the standard `mount` command (which requires root) you can mount drives using `udisks` and `dbus` with your standard user.

To do this it is useful (but not required) to know a few things about the drive first:

1. What device it is (i.e. `/dev/sdb1`)
2. what filesystem it uses.

Knowing these you can use a simple command to mount a drive from the command line.

```
gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.UDisks --object-path /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/<device> --method org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device.FilesystemMount "<filesystem>" []
```

this call should echo the path it is mounted at if the mount succeeds.

To unmount drives mounted in this way you can run:

```
gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.UDisks --object-path /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/<device> --method org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device.FilesystemUnmount []
```

---

N.B. the `<device>` is simply the end of the path to it. So for example if what you want to mount is at `/dev/sdb2` then you would put `sdb2` in place of `<device>`.

---

If you do not know which device it is or what filesystem it uses do not fear. You can easily print out all that information with this little command:

```
gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.UDisks --object-path /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices --recurse --only-properties | grep -E "(readonly .+ (IdLabel|IdType|Device(IsMounted|IsDrive|File) ).*|\}|.*\{)"
```

This will print out something like this:

```
node /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices {
  node /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda {
    interface org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device {
        readonly s IdLabel = '';
        readonly s IdType = '';
        readonly s IdUsage = '';
        readonly b DeviceIsMounted = false;
        readonly s DeviceFile = '/dev/sda';
    };
  };
  node /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda1 {
    interface org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device {
        readonly s IdLabel = 'SYSTEM';
        readonly s IdType = 'ntfs';
        readonly s IdUsage = 'filesystem';
        readonly b DeviceIsMounted = false;
        readonly s DeviceFile = '/dev/sda1';
    };
  };
  node /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda2 {
    interface org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device {
        readonly s IdLabel = 'Windows7';
        readonly s IdType = 'ntfs';
        readonly s IdUsage = 'filesystem';
        readonly b DeviceIsMounted = true;
        readonly s DeviceFile = '/dev/sda2';
    };
  };
  node /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda3 {
    interface org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device {
        readonly s IdLabel = 'Recovery';
        readonly s IdType = 'ntfs';
        readonly s IdUsage = 'filesystem';
        readonly b DeviceIsMounted = false;
        readonly s DeviceFile = '/dev/sda3';
    };
  };
  node /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda4 {
    interface org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device {
        readonly s IdLabel = '';
        readonly s IdType = '';
        readonly s IdUsage = '';
        readonly b DeviceIsMounted = false;
        readonly s DeviceFile = '/dev/sda4';
    };
  };
  node /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda5 {
    interface org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device {
        readonly s IdLabel = '';
        readonly s IdType = 'ext4';
        readonly s IdUsage = 'filesystem';
        readonly b DeviceIsMounted = true;
        readonly s DeviceFile = '/dev/sda5';
    };
  };
  node /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda6 {
    interface org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device {
        readonly s IdLabel = '';
        readonly s IdType = 'swap';
        readonly s IdUsage = 'other';
        readonly b DeviceIsMounted = false;
        readonly s DeviceFile = '/dev/sda6';
    };
  };
  node /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda7 {
    interface org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device {
        readonly s IdLabel = '';
        readonly s IdType = 'ext4';
        readonly s IdUsage = 'filesystem';
        readonly b DeviceIsMounted = true;
        readonly s DeviceFile = '/dev/sda7';
    };
  };
  node /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdb {
    interface org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device {
        readonly s IdLabel = '';
        readonly s IdType = '';
        readonly s IdUsage = '';
        readonly b DeviceIsMounted = false;
        readonly s DeviceFile = '/dev/sdb';
    };
  };
  node /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdb1 {
    interface org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device {
        readonly s IdLabel = 'USB DRIVE';
        readonly s IdType = 'vfat';
        readonly s IdUsage = 'filesystem';
        readonly b DeviceIsMounted = false;
        readonly s DeviceFile = '/dev/sdb1';
    };
  };
  node /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sr0 {
    interface org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device {
        readonly s IdLabel = '';
        readonly s IdType = '';
        readonly s IdUsage = '';
        readonly b DeviceIsMounted = false;
        readonly s DeviceFile = '/dev/sr0';
    };
  };
};
```

Those that have `IdUsage = 'filesystem'` may be mounted using the above command.

This means that, for example, if i wanted to mount the device 'USB DRIVE' i would run the command

```
gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.UDisks --object-path /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdb1 --method org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device.FilesystemMount "vfat" []
```

---

These commands all work using the `dbus` messaging system, the same way that `Nautilus` and other file managers auto-mount things. In these commands we are sending various objects (i.e. `/org/freedesktop/...` messages asking them to mount and unmount certain devices. They might or might not do this depending on the permissions one has been given in `PolicyKit`.

Using similar commands one can control almost every aspect of ones experience in Ubuntu and simulate most system programs and functions (i.e. shutdown, volume change, etc.).

Comment: The 2015 way is ```gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.UDisks2 --object-path /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives --recurse --only-properties```

Answer (score 5):

You can also automatically mount USB devices on Ubuntu Server with the help of USBmount.

Make sure you run apt-get update/upgrade before starting the installation:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now install USBmount from the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install usbmount
```

USBmount mounts all USB drives in `/media/usb*` (usb0, usb1, usb2 ...)

Now plug a USB drive and wait for it to be detected and mounted. As long as the host OS supports the File System it should be mounted.

To verify whether the USB drive was mounted correctly you can use `df -h` to view all available drives and their respective mount points

To un-mount a drive you can use umount.

```
sudo umount /media/usb0
```

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package usbmount`

Answer (score 4):

That's simple. When I want to use a usb drive in terminal I do this:

Create a folder in `/media` with:

```
mkdir /media/mountDrive
```

This folder will be used for the mount point. Use this command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /media/mountDrive
```

`sdd1` is the first partition of my USB. Then you can navigate to folder you already mounted with

```
cd /media/mountDrive
```

If you want to list the files in drive you can use the `ls` command.

To unmount the drive you can use

```
sudo umount /dev/sdd1
```

Note that in my system the usb drive is `/dev/sdd1`, but in your system it may be something different. To find out what it is use the `df` command to see all disks connected at the present time.

Answer (score 0):

I will not add about how to mount the drive. However since the asker also asked what the best command to use to copy the data over, I will answer that since it was not answered as far as I can tell.

I would recommend first creating a folder on the drive (even if it is empty) to back your stuff into to provide organization. Something along the lines of `mkdir <mountpath>/mybackup` should do it.

Second, I would use rsync to copy everything over. Do something along the lines of `rsync -r ~/* <mountpoint>/mybackup`. You can also use `cp -r` if you want, however, I have found that doing so doesn't do quite everything that you would expect all of the time.