# How to Mount USB to access files from Terminal

Tags: usb, mount

I can access files from emplorer or Nautilus but how to do the same job from Terminal .

How to Mount USB to access files from Terminal. And whats the complete process of doing it.

This will be my first time of Mounting

Comment: This post should be merged with this one: http://askubuntu.com/q/37767/62483