# Why LibreOffice keeps saying the document is locked for editing?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, read-only

I created file LinuxNotes.odt some time ago and yesterday I edited that same file at my work place and I was in Guest account when I edited that file.

Now whenever I open that file any where else Ubuntu slap me with **Document in Use** error Message.

What's the cause?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There should be a hidden "lock" file created by LibreOffice and, for some reason, not automatically removed when the document was closed.

Open the folder where the document is located and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show the hidden files, then search for a file with a name similar to your document file name, but starting with ".~lock.". Remove that lock file and you're done.

Comment: Hahahhaha great what a hidden protection thanks for the help .

Now goto this link and help me out.. [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/181800/how-to-mount-usb-to-access-files-from-terminal)

Comment: Anyone know why this happens though?