# 12.04 logs session into small terminal window

Tags: 12.04, login, session

I upgraded from 11.04 to 12.04 and when it was all finished i couldn't login unless i went in as a guest.

So following a lot of pages on here i deleted the `~/Xauthority` High seemed to work.

However just before that i also ran `sudo chmod -R  $USER:$USER $HOME`

Now after I've entered my password i get a small terminal window appear in the top left with me logged in.

I can't seem to find anything around this. Any ideas?

I can't help but think I've set all the files to something they shouldn't all be.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the contents of `~/.xsession-errors`? And `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`? You can mount a USB stick using [this instructions](http://askubuntu.com/q/37767/169736) and copying the files just with `cp /var/log/Xorg.0.log /media/usb/`.

Comment: I'll try it tmrw night when i get a chance. Thanks for the reply Braiam

Comment: xsession-errors is empty, I thought that maybe it's because I hadn't run it. So when I did, I got the error

'User not authorized to run the X server , aborted'. So googling that I found the following page (http://www.khattam.info/solved-user-not-authorized-to-run-the-x-server-2010-11-26.html) and did 

sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common

but it said that it was already running on display 0. Attaching the Xorg.0.log in the next comment

Comment: It wouldn't let me add it as a comment, not enough space, so I put it in the answer. Hope that's ok...

Comment: You can upload files to http://paste.ubuntu.com then copy the link and paste it in your question....

Comment: Braiam....I'm so sorry....I didn't notice, but I thought I'd try out a diff graphic 'session' like Unity 2D instead of Unity, and when I went to chose one, it was defaulting to recovery console!!!

THAT'S why it kept bringing up a terminal window!!

So sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: If you want you can put that as an answer instead... through it will be a public embarrassment :P.

Answer (score 1):

You may have accidentally choosen *the failsafe session* from the session menu in the login screen.

When you are on the login screen choose your user and click on the Ubuntu logo and choose *Unity* or *Unity 2D* from the list and login.

[image]