# How can I make a folder in a Pen-Drive using terminal?

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I had opened a Pen-Drive in my system and I thought to open my Pen-Drive from terminal and copy the needed file from system to Pen-Drive from terminal only. But I was wondering how I can do that. Can you please suggest me procedure for doing the same?

Comment: Similar or the same: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37767/how-to-access-a-usb-flash-drive-from-the-terminal-how-can-i-mount-a-flash-driv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually all mounted devices including system partitions will be in a directory named as media.

Open your terminal and type the following one after one

`cd /`

`cd media`

There you can find your partitions including your Pen-Drive or USB device.

Next with `cp` command you can copy and paste the data from Pen-Drive to system and vice-versa.

Syntax:

```
cp  <source-path> <destination-path>
```

Comment: When I type whatever you said and then type ls, it is not showing me anything. I mean in media, it is not showing me anything. Why?

Comment: It will show your username and in your name folder you will see your USB or Pen_drive

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get it. Please elaborate. Thanks for you response.

Comment: If you change to media with `cd /media` then you will find your username there. so you have to do like `cd /media/<username_here>`

Comment: My media folder is empty.

Comment: it shouldnt , did your pendrive mounted ?

Comment: pendrive mounted means?