# How do I install wpa-supplicant on an offline server?

Tags: software-installation, wpa-supplicant

Alright, I have an Ubuntu server on which I couldn't connect to my [WPA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11i-2004) secured Wi-Fi network.

Apparently I need wpa-supplicant to be able to connect to it
(see *[How do I connect to a WPA wifi network using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line)*), but ironically I can't download it being offline. So, how can I download wpa-supplicant, get it on a USB device and install it on the server? I have no idea so far...

PS: I only have a Mac as a primary machine, so I can't download it from another Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can doownload most/all packages from the main Ubuntu repositories from [`http://packages.ubuntu.com`](http://packages.ubuntu.com). You can search for it from [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), find it from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), and download it from one of these pages:

- 32bit: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/wpasupplicant/download
- 64bit: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/wpasupplicant/download

The problem here is that some packages it needs may to be downloaded as well - you can test that by trying to install it, and seeing if it exits with any errors.

Another way of doing it would be to run `apt-get install --print-uris wpasupplicant`<sup>**[1]**</sup> on the server, and downloading it with the machine that has internet access, and transferring the deb file(s). This will likely be better as it will list other packages it needs as dependencies.

For example, it might give on a Ubuntu 14.04 64bit machine [`http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wpa/wpasupplicant_2.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb`](http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wpa/wpasupplicant_2.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb).

Once you have managed to get the needed deb files, you can install it with `dpkg -i /PATH/TO/FILE(S).deb`.

<sup>**1**: this will likely only work if the machine has had access to the internet to update the package lists - the `print-uris` just tells it to print what was going to download instead of downloading it</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but how do i transfer the file once i download it on another machine? I mean, i can put it in a usb, but from there how would i read it on the server? EDIT: Okay ,so i download the .deb file on the machine, transfer it to a usb, put it in the server, and then running dpkg -i?

Comment: If you need to mount the USB on the machine, read [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/37767/178596). You can install the package with `dpkg -i`. It will be under the mountpoint you have chosen, you can do this by going `cd /media/MOUNTPOINT` and running `ls` to see if it is there.

Comment: Great! So it explains how to mount it. Once it's mounted i should be able to install it with just dpkg -i, right?

Comment: @user3504154 - `dpkg -i /PATH/TO/FILE.deb`. Glad to be of help :D

Answer (score 0):

I did run into this problem today. I needed to download the following packages:

wpasupplicant_2.9-1ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb
libnl-route-3-200_3.4.0-1_amd64.deb
libpcsclite1_1.8.26-3_amd64.deb
libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

I did download it from https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/ . After installation I'm able to connect to internet via WiFi. The server wasn't connected to internet before, its brand new install. It's possible to check what exact package you need to install if you check logs with command `grep wpa /var/log/syslog`. You will see errors like on the screen below which indicates what package is missing.

[image: grep wpa /var/log/syslog]