# How to copy a file from USB drive

Tags: command-line, usb-drive

How can I copy, or just access a file on the USB drive from Ubuntu Server?
[This answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/37775/411423) does not work, I am getting

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

which no one explained how to solve.
This happens after I type

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/usb
```

where /dev/sdc is supposedly my USB.

How can I do it?

Comment: What file system is on your USB drive?

Comment: Are you sure? How did you find out that?

Comment: because I also have a windows PC, on which I made that USB..

Comment: First thing you need to do is to show what command line you used to generate that error.  Otherwise, nobody can tell you what you might be doing wrong.  It may be a simple syntax error.

Comment: there, edited it

Comment: That you created it on Windows doesn't mean it's FAT32. It could also be NTFS or even FAT16 (though that's unlikely). Please [edit] your question and include the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc`.

Comment: `sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/usb` is not the same than `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/usb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specify the filesystem type with the `-t` option. As described in `man mount`:

```
   -t, --types fstype
          The argument following the -t is used to indicate the filesystem
          type.  The filesystem types which are currently supported depend
          on the running  kernel.   See  /proc/filesystems  and  /lib/mod‐
          ules/$(uname  -r)/kernel/fs  for a complete list of the filesys‐
          tems.  The most common are ext2, ext3, ext4, xfs,  btrfs,  vfat,
          sysfs, proc, nfs and cifs.
```

So, to mount a FAT32 (vfat) drive, you would run:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdc /media/usb
```

However, you don't mount devices, you mount partitions. What you're after is probably:

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/usb
```

Or, if it still complains:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /media/usb
```

For more details, update your question with the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc`.

Answer (score 0):

Launch the app gnome-disk-utility, find your usb on the sidebar, and click the triangle play button under the filesystem graph and it should mount it.

Like this:
[image: mountusb:]

Comment: I am on ubuntu server, sorry forgot to mention it in the tags