# How to mount an image file without root?

Tags: mount, root

I have a file with an ext4 file system in it and want to mount it without using sudo every time (the script should run with user rights). The file I want to mount and the folder which I want to mount it too both are in my home directory which is encrypted, so I can't put the file location into `/etc/fstab`.

I tried `fusermount` but I always get error messages like "fusermount: extra arguments after the mountpoint".

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/403192/229499?

Comment: @muru Thank you, unfortunately this is about ext2. Even if write access is possible I won't have journaling because ext2 didn't have journaling. I need journaling.

Comment: Then you'll have to live with having to be root somehow.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32157/10805  What was the `fusermount` command you tried?

Comment: Check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096294/mount-without-root-permission

Answer (score 3):

You can use `udiskctl`:

```
$ udisksctl loop-setup --file your_file.iso
Mapped file your_file.iso as /dev/loop6.
```

Now, your file is mapped to a `block device`, and you can mount it as:

```
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/loop6
Mounted /dev/loop6 at /media/user/your_file.
```

when you're done, unmount is using:

```
$ udisksctl unmount -b /dev/loop6
Unmounted /dev/loop6.
```

finally, delete it by:

```
$ udisksctl loop-delete -b /dev/loop6
```

Have fun!

Comment: I tried mounting some Linux image I had laying around (`kali-linux-2019.1a-amd64.iso`) but I always get: `Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/loop5 is not a mountable filesystem.` (With the device number varying, of course.) This happens even when I try to mount it read-only. Mounting it read-only via `sudo mount` works just fine.

Comment: use `udisksctl loop-setup --file your_file.iso` again, so it gives you a new loop device, and mount that one (e.g. `/dev/loop8`). In my OS, it doesn't work using `loop6` and don't know why. @UTF-8

Answer (score 3):

### [GNOME Disk Image Mounter](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks)

Beside [`udisksctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/) and [`guestmount`](http://libguestfs.org/guestmount.1.html) (`libguestfs-tools`) you can just:

```
gnome-disk-image-mounter ~/ISOs/file.iso
```

[From manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gnome-disk-image-mounter.1.html):

> Accept both regular files and GVfs URIs (such as smb://filer/media/file.iso)")
>
> By default the disk images are attached read-only, use the option --writable to change this.

- `gnome-disk-image-mounter` is part of `gnome-disk-utility` package, which also brings `gnome-disks` (run it with `-h` for more info).
- Despite its name [you can use it on KDE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423848/209677) without any gnome dependency.
- Also check [`gio mount`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gio.1.html) and `udisksctl`.
- See also [How to access a usb flash drive from the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37767/how-to-access-a-usb-flash-drive-from-the-terminal)

Answer (score 2):

You can have it in /etc/fstab. My home directory is encrypted, yet:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=ext4_file bs=1024 count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1,0 MB) copied, 0,0341311 s, 30,7 MB/s
$ /sbin/mkfs.ext4 -F ext4_file
mke2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)

Filesystem too small for a journal
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Creating filesystem with 1024 1k blocks and 128 inodes

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

$ grep ext4_directory /etc/fstab
/home/alessandro/ext4_file /home/alessandro/ext4_directory ext4 noauto,user 0 0
$ mount ext4_directory
$ mount | grep ext4_directory
/home/alessandro/ext4_file on /home/alessandro/ext4_directory type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user=alessandro)
```

Comment: If he says that because it's encrypted, he can't put it in /etc/fstab, he's right. That doesn't fully mount it.

Comment: Well, nothing is stopping me from writing it into `/etc/fstab`, so I tried it before I posted this questing. I knew that it probably wouldn't mount it but assumed that maybe it would fail without consequences and that the fact that it's in `/etc/fstab` enabled me to mount it without root. Unfortunately this caused my system to fail to boot and I had to remove the line in order to be able to use my machine again.

Comment: David, all I wrote I performed on a PC with /home mounted on an encrypted partition. And it did work. And I cannot see why it couldn't.

Comment: UTF-8, for it to work /home must be mounted before your file. Or you set your file not to be mounted automatically, like I set it to be in the directions I gave you, they are a real-case scenario.

Comment: Who put the `ext4_file` file in `fstab`?? Didn't you skip anything?

Comment: Of course I put the ext4_file file in fstab, who else?
I didn't skip anything, I fully reported all the steps I performed. If you think something's amiss please repeat those steps and verify for yourself.
Would you still believe something was left out, please state clearly what and why.

Answer (score 1):

**`guestmount` libguestfs trickery**

```
sudo apt-get install libguestfs-tools

# Workarounds for Ubuntu 18.04 bugs.
# https://serverfault.com/questions/246835/convert-directory-to-qemu-kvm-virtual-disk-image/916697#916697
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/.guestfs-*
echo dash | sudo tee /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/zz-dash-packages
sudo chmod +r /boot/vmlinuz-*

# Create a test image.
mkdir sysroot
dd if=/dev/urandom of=sysroot/myfile bs=1024 count=1024
virt-make-fs --format=raw --type=ext2 sysroot sysroot.ext2

# Mount it, have fun, unmount!
mkdir -p mnt
# /dev/sda becuase we have a raw filesystem.
guestmount -a sysroot.ext2.qcow2 -m /dev/sda mnt
cmp sysroot/myfile mnt/myfile
guestunmount mnt
```

Relies on:

- userland implementation of the filesystems
- FUSE

Docs: http://libguestfs.org/guestmount.1.html

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, libguestfs-tools 1:1.36.13-1ubuntu3.