# Mount without root permission

Tags: usb, permissions, mount, xubuntu

I use Xubuntu. When I plug in my USB, I can simply mount and open it by clicking on its icon, but when I want to mount it from the command line, it needs root permission.

Why? And how can I mount my USB (the command line) without root permission? I can't put it in `/etc/fstab`, because it needs root permission.

<sub>Note:
I don't want to mount an ISO file. My question was marked as duplicated but the target question had no valid answer. If you want to flag as duplicated, please first check the target question, and then add the duplicated flag. Thanks.</sub>

Comment: Check that answer, somebody put the mount line in `/etc/fstab`. You JUST can edit it using root permission. @PabloBianchi

Comment: However, thanks to you, I answered that question too;) @PabloBianchi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto-mount from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342188/how-to-auto-mount-from-command-line).

Comment: @Melebius FYI We are *unable* to edit the "duplicate target" list - those are handled automatically by the system based on flags.  Your comment here alone to add the link to the other potential duplicate was sufficient enough,

Comment: @ThomasWard Really? It’s mentioned as the first option on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306326/allow-users-to-suggest-edits-to-the-duplicate-list.

Comment: @Melebius yes, but that meta post is a **feature request**.  It's not a list of current functionality.

Comment: @ThomasWard OP says: _“Here are the options I **have**…”_ And what about this? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdXY` we can mount without root permission, just like what gui does.

Comment: In my case it asks me for a password here as well :/