# Identifying backup devices with deja-dup/duplicity

Tags: deja-dup, duplicity

I am using the Ubuntu aic7xxx module (which is controlling an Adaptec 21960 scsi controller which in turn is connected to a Dell LTO tape unit).  I have successfully installed deja-dup and duplicity.  What I am trying to do is to verify that the scsi controller and LTO drive are being recognized by Ubuntu. Question: Deja-dup does locate any devices, only folders/drives (there are two hard drives). Is duplicity/deja-dup only for use with folders/directories? If they are, is there a list of Ubuntu supported back-up software that is newer than 2014 ([Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)) that Ubuntu supports somewhere? I ask because I know that as software develops, what works in 2014 may not be supported in 2016.

Comment: Thank you.  Reading other posts, I found the command lsscsi (which I had to install) and it does show that I have the LTO  and it is located at /dev/st0. I guess now I somehow have to get deja-dup to see /dev/st0.

Comment: Thank you user68186.  After having used Windows for so long, this is like having to learn DOS all over again, except that there is no convenient "book for dummies" to look up stuff. Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Need a bit of clarification.  How dies /dev/st0 become /mnt/some-folder? Wait..I think I got it...using this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/37767/how-to-access-a-usb-flash-drive-from-the-terminal-how-can-i-mount-a-flash-driv but instead of a usb device I have a st0 device.

Comment: I am glad you figured it out. I have converted my comments to a proper answer. You should accept the answer as correct so that others with similar problem can easily find it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a two step process. **First**, you need identify the the Dell LTO scsi tape drive as recognized by the computer. **Second**, you need to mount the device as a folder/directory.

## First Step: Find the device

To list all the scsi devices, you need a tool called `lssci`. You may need to install this first. Open a command line by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo apt-get install lsscsi
```

Enter your password when prompted. The cursor won't move while you enter your password. That is normal. Once `lsscsi` is installed, enter the command:

```
lsscsi -l
```

This will list your SCSI devices like the DELL LTO. It will look something like `/dev/st0`. `/dev` is a special virtual folder for devices in Linux. The devices listed there needs to be mounted on a regular folder before they can be used by any program like `Deja Dup`.

## Second Step: Mount the device

Ubuntu mounts devices that are not always connected under the folder `/media/`. First, see if the device is already mounted there or not. It will be something like `/media/Dell_LTO`. If this is so, we are almost done. If not, you need to first create the `Dell_LTO` folder under `/media/` by the following command:

```
sudo  mkdir /media/DELL_LTO
```

You will need to do this once only. Once the actual folder is created, you will have to tell the computer to use that folder as the mount point for the Dell LTO devise.

```
sudo mount /dev/st0 /media/DELL_LTO
```

Here I have used `DELL_LTO` as an example. You can call this folder whatever you want. Remember Linux is case sensitive. So a folder call DELL_LTO is very different from a another folder called dell_lto, or dEll_lTo.

Hope this helps