# emergency mode at start up after update

Tags: boot, updates, startup

After updating Ubuntu it now boots into emergency mode. I'm new to this OS.

If anyone can help me out with the codes that would be great. I do not have the OS on a CD or USB.

[image: Emergency boot mode image]

Comment: what happens if you type:   ctrl-d   as it offers

Comment: it goes purple for like 2 seconds and goes back to the emergency screen mode. Then when I hold it it just starts loading as its starting up but does nothing just stays on the purple ubuntu page.

Comment: I was going to post a new question because I'm having the same exact issue upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

If you do have high value files not backed up then I suggest you obtain a Ubuntu liveCD [or usb] and boot off it (which should avoid this screen ) ... once booted up then plug in a memory stick and backup treasured files/dirs

Now that your are booted up off the Ubuntu LiveCD open up a terminal ( ctrl+alt+T ) and issue

```
sudo -i    # to toggle into root
fdisk -l
```

at bottom you should see something like this

```
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048 1431805951 1431803904 682.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1431807998 1465147391   33339394  15.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1431808000 1465147391   33339392  15.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Identify your boot device ( the one with * for me its /dev/sda1 )

issue

```
umount /dev/sda1 
fsck -y /dev/sda1 # leave off -y if you want prompts to OK fix actions
reboot
```

The motive for booting off Ubuntu LiveCD is your normal drive can then be unmounted ... something you (cannot/should not) do when booted from it

Comment: But if he has bash access he should be able to back up his files.  SCP to another computer on the same network. I'm in the same situation hoping to restore though.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride How did you get into that pickle ?

Comment: On restart I was asked if wanted to upgrade to 16.04. I clicked yes.

Comment: doubt this will help but here is the bottom of the output when I use 'journalctl -xb' http://imgur.com/zEySMOF

Answer (score 1):

**Recovering your files:**

I'm in the situation and I was able to recover my files. You'll need a usb.

1. enter your password as prompted
2. create a folder to mount usb to:

   sudo  mkdir /media/usb
3. [mount usb](https://askubuntu.com/a/37775/135947) *(I wasn't able to use the 'fdisk -l' command so I guessed sdb1 and got lucky)*:

   sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
4. Go to your home folder and copy the files you want to keep into your usb:

   cd /home/yourUserName/

   ls # see what files you want

   sudo cp -r myfiles/ /media/usb/