# How to recover the corrupted flash drive ?

Tags: mount, flash

My Flash drive is corrupted and I am trying to recover it using this answer in ask ubuntu  whose link is this https://askubuntu.com/a/37775/658451. 
I have tried

```
   lsblk
sudo blkid
sudo fdisk -l
```

and here is the result snapshot 
[image]

my targeted drive is **sdb of** **size 14.5 GB**

But when I try to mount a mountpoint I got an error which is

> mount: /media/moeed/usb: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on
>   /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

I have also tried

```
pmount /dev/sdb
```

I got this error on it

> NTFS signature is missing.
>   Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument
>   The device '/dev/sdb' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
>   Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
>   partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
>   NTFS signature is missing.
>   Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument
>   The device '/dev/sdb' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
>   Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
>   partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

Kindly Help me recover the drive. If you need any other information please tell me. Thanks :)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/47700/fix-corrupt-ntfs-partition-without-windows

Comment: @JoKeR I have tried to fix the ntfs partition by using sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sdb but I got an error saying NTFS signature is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was done with merely few steps after trying a lot. Just open DISK and the usb drive was shown in it. I tried to format from here and my drive was mounted after few seconds :) Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use gparted to reformat it to fat32? It doesn't need to be mounted for that? Sorry if it's a stupid answer, I just thought it might work!

To install gparted:

```
 sudo apt-get install gparted
```

To use it:

```
sudo gparted
```

Comment: It didn't work for me.. I got this as a result of sudo gparted 
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/-.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/run-user-1000.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/run-user-125.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/tmp.mount → /dev/null.
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
(gpartedbin:5005): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
Removed /run/systemd/system/-.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/run-user-1000.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/run-user-125.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/tmp.mount.

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I dont know then.