# How can I get the /dev/ location of a USB device?

Tags: usb

I want to get the location in `/dev` of a USB device connected to my machine.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by dev location, what is the purpose?

Comment: I need the dev location of the micrcontroller I want to program.

Comment: It should be in the form of `/dev/ttyACM0`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to known the drive name in the `/dev/` folder, I normally

- disconnect USB
- in a terminal, type `dmesg -w`
- insert USB

And the kernel will show some messages including the name of your device. 
Other options are

```
lsblk
sudo blkid
sudo fdisk -l
```

And you may want to check this to mount it.
[How to access a usb flash drive from the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37767/how-to-access-a-usb-flash-drive-from-the-terminal)

Comment: Microcontrollers and FPGA don't mount like USB flash drives, so the last line is sort of irrelevant to the question, but the answer overall is proper, hence +1