# Access an e-reader via USB on the command-line

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, 22.10

I have a Likebook Mars e-reader. When I plug it into my laptop with a USB cable, it appears in PCManFM-Qt, and I can access the files on it graphically from there:

[image: A screenshot of PCManFM-Qt with "Likebook T80D" in the sidebar]

That works okay. What I want to do is browse, read, and write files on the command line with `cd`, `ls`, `cp`, etc. But the e-reader doesn't seem to be reachable via anywhere I can `cd` to in the real filesystem (even if I've already looked at some of the files in PCManFM-Qt, which in other cases seems to be necessary). Having looked at the question [How to access a usb flash drive from the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37767/how-to-access-a-usb-flash-drive-from-the-terminal/865453), I tried `lsblk`, but the e-reader doesn't seem to be listed:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 653.6G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0    16M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   300G  0 part /media/hippo/A4A60CCCA60CA142
```

`df` provides no hints, either:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.6G  1.9M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  643G  240G  371G  40% /
tmpfs           7.6G     0  7.6G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1  300M   33M  267M  11% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   92K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p4  300G  154G  147G  52% /media/hippo/A4A60CCCA60CA142
```

Comment: Are there any mounts under `/run/user/<your_UID>/`? For example, `/run/user/1000/gvfs` is where Nautilus puts mounts for my user.

Comment: @user535733 Bingo. Looks like it shows up as `/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=Boyue_Likebook-T80D_CNBT80D20200601412`. Thanks.

Comment: @guiverc Yes, the PCManFM in question is PCManFM-Qt. I don't think the old version is often used these days.

Comment: `pcmanfm` is a different program  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/pcmanfm) to `pcmanfm-qt` used by LXQt/Lubuntu (https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/pcmanfm-qt).  Yes the GTK2 program is used a lot (server users with LXDE added commonly), but not by Lubuntu.  They are not the same application.  Lubuntu doesn't use *deprecated* GTK2 apps.

Comment: I see, I'd thought that "PCManFM" would be unambiguous by this point. I've edited the question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in the comments by user535733, plugging in the e-reader creates a directory in `` /run/user/`id -u`/gvfs `` for the e-reader's filesystem. The name of the new directory (`mtp:host=Boyue_Likebook-T80D_CNBT80D20200601412` in my case) seems to be consistent for a given device, even after the host machine reboots.

The underlying protocol here seems to be [Media Transfer Protocol (MTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol), as opposed to the more familiar USB mass storage.

Comment: MTP was the same headache I had with my Kindle Paperwhite; Did you find a software solution to browse, read, and write files?

Comment: @BaTycoon I'm not sure I understand your question. My answer here describes how to find a directory that corresponds to the device filesystem. You can then use whatever file manager you like with it.